# How can auto create uuid column with django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using django to create database tables for mysql,and I want it can create a column which type is uuid,I hope it can generate the uuid by itself,that means each time insert a record,I needn't specify a uuid for the model object.How can I make it,thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you're using Django >= 1.8, you can [use a `UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield):

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Passing `default = uuid.uuid4` auto-populates new records with a random UUID (but note that this will be done in Python code, not at the database level).

---

If you're using an older version of Django, you can either upgrade, or [use `django-extensions`, which provides a `UUIDField` as well](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/field_extensions.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer,what does **but note that this will be done in Python code, not at the database level** means?

Comment: @FireSun it means the UUID will be generated by Django calling `uuid.uuid4()`, not by your database. If you're only using Django to insert records, this won't be a problem for you.

Comment: The downside of doing it this way (as I found out) is if this is done as a migration, then all existing rows in the Db will get the same UUID value.

Comment: To avoid existing rows getting the same UUID value, follow the 'Migrations that add unique fields' example in the Django docs: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/writing-migrations/#:~:text=Migrations%20that%20add%20unique%20fields&text=Modify%20the%20respective%20field%20according,Run%20the%20makemigrations%20command.)

Comment: @BogeyMan exactly, I am facing the same issue, any soln so far?